# HTML - How to Open base64 Image String in New Tab

Tags: html, web-applications, base64, download

I'm trying to create an HTML button that will open an image in the form of a base64 string in a new tab. I made a trial version that works fine with static images:

```
<button type = "button" id = "submit_btn" class="contact100-form-btn">
    <a href="static/static_filename.png" class="contact100-form-btn" target="_blank">
        Download
    </a>
</button>
```

Now I would like to do things dynamically (the application involves each user creating a new image, so serving from a single static filename will not work). My first attempt:

```
<button type = "button" id = "submit_btn" class="contact100-form-btn">
    <a href="data:image/png;base64,{img_io}" class="contact100-form-btn" target="_blank">
      Download
    </a>
</button>
```

Where `img_io` is the base64 encoded image string.

Clicking the button does nothing, and prompts the message `Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL` in the Chrome developer console. I tried adding download explicitly:

```
<button type = "button" id = "submit_btn" class="contact100-form-btn">
    <a download="filename.png" href="data:image/png;base64,{img_io}" class="contact100-form-btn" target="_blank">
      Download
    </a>
</button>
```

This causes the image to download successfully on Chrome, but does not work on Firefox. Does anyone know how to make the base64 image string open in a new tab? Or as a fallback a create direct download option that works across browsers? Preferably in pure HTML, as this is part of a python based web app and I know next to nothing about Javascript.

Thanks